# Regarding synchronized methods in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have a question about synchronization of methods in Java.

Consider a class with 3 `synchronized` methods.

```
class MyClass{

    public synchronized void methodA(){ ... }

    public synchronized void methodB(){ ... }

    public synchronized void methodC(){ ... }

}
```

Consider `myObject`, an instance of `myClass`. **Which of the following is true?**

**Option 1:**

It's impossible for a thread to run **any** `synchronized` method in `myObject`, while a different thread is running **any** synchronized method in `myObject`.

For example, while thread 1 is running `methodA()` of the instance `myObject`, thread 2 can't run **any** of the methods `methodA()`, `methodB()` and `methodC()`.

**Option 2:**

It's impossible for a thread to run a specific `synchronized` method in `myObject`, while **that specific method** is being run by another thread.

For example, while thread 1 is running `methodA()` of the instance `myObject`, thread 2 can't run the method `methodA()`, but **can** run `methodB()` or `methodC()`. (Meaning, the three synchronized methods aren't 'connected').

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do two synchronized methods execute simultaneously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160023/do-two-synchronized-methods-execute-simultaneously)

Comment: +1 for this nice question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first option is true because there is basically one lock used for all the methods.

Comment: So while thread 1 runs methodA() in a specific instance, thread 2 can't run methodA(), can't run methodB(), and can't run methodC()?

Comment: Thanks :) Will accept the answer when the 7 minuts are up