# Does synchronized directive in two functions means they both will be available just for one thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have class that has two synchronized functions. That means that if `thread-0` executed `proc1()` and `thread-1` would like to do the same with `proc1()` it will wait `thread-0` 
to finish with `proc1()`. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

But what if `thread-0` executes `proc1()` and `thread-1` wants to execute `proc2()`? Should `thread-1` needs to wait when `proc1()` will be finished by `thread-0`?

In other words - synchronized functions are synchronized in class object level or just function level?

```
public class MyClass
{
public synchronized void proc1()
{
...
}
public synchronized void proc2()
{
...
}

}
```

Comment: This is one of those examples where you can just try it yourself.

Comment: No sure I can, since you never know when system will decide to switch to another thread.

Comment: In this case you most certainly can. If you want a test with two threads and put a sleep in each method, you'll notice either both threads enter then sleep or one thread enters then sleeps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important thing you need to know about `synchronized` is that a synchronized method or a synchronized block always synchronized on some *object*, and no two threads will ever be allowed to synchronize on the same object at the same time.

In the case of a synchronized block, the synchronization object is explicitly provided.  In this example, it's whatever object is referenced by the variable `foo`:

```
synchronized(foo) {
    ...
}
```

In the case of a synchronized instance method, the synchronization object is `this` (i.e., the object on which the method was invoked.)  In this case, an instance of `MyClass`:

```
class MyClass
    synchronized void proc1() {
        ...
    }
}
```

And, if it's a synchronized `static` method, the synchronization object is the class object.  In this case, it would be `MyClass.class`:

```
class MyClass {
    static synchronized void proc2() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: So that means that proc1() and proc2() are synchronized on the same "this". And this menas different threads will not be allowed to run proc1() and proc2() of the same object? So answer is "on object level"

Comment: @vico - Correct! In addition it is worth bearing in mind that if `proc1` called `proc2` you alreeady hold the lock on `this` so you are allowed to use `proc2`.

Answer (score 0):

`synchronized` is applied at the object (instance) level, and a thread accessing a `synchronized` method will lock the object. So if you're dealing with the same object instance, then `thread-0` will have to release the lock before `thread-1` can access any methods on it. `thread-1` would be in a blocked state until it can acquire the lock.

It is explained further here: [Do two synchronized methods execute simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160023/do-two-synchronized-methods-execute-simultaneously)